# Why can my function not find the variable that I input into it?

Tags: r, function

So when cleaning data I have to apply a function that removes all rows in which a certain column ends with the string "Total".

I tried to apply it the str_detect to all columns, but it did not work.

Then, I thought I would create a function. I'm also in the process of learning to get better at creating functions. But I can somehow not wrap my head around them. The normal code looks like this:

```
D3 <- D3 %>%
   dplyr::filter(!stringr::str_detect(institution, "Total$"))
```

I have several variables, where institution is supposed to be. So I wrote this function:

```
remove_total <- function(data, x) {
   data %>% 
     dplyr::filter(!stringr::str_detect(x, "Total$"))
 }
```

Then when I try to run it, the following appears:

```
remove_total(D3, institution)
```

! Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `!stringr::str_detect(x, "Total$")`.
x object 'institution' not found

When I run rlang::last_trace(), I get this:

! Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `!stringr::str_detect(x, "Total$")`.
x object 'institution' not found
Backtrace:

1. global remove_total(D3, institution)
2. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
3. dplyr h(simpleError(msg, call))

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we pass unquoted variables, use curly-curly operator (`{{}}`) to evaluate

```
remove_total <- function(data, x) {
   data %>% 
     dplyr::filter(!stringr::str_detect({{x}}, "Total$"))
 }
```

-testing

```
remove_total(D3, institution)
```

---

If there are many variables, use `if_any/if_all` (for removing rows where are `any` column having the substring or `all` the columns respectively)

```
D3 %>%
    filter(!if_any(cols_of_interest, ~ str_detect(.x, "Total$")))
```